# Solving for b for equation $3a−5=−4b+1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I have a math problem, and I'm trying to solve for 'b'. The problem answer shows that the first step is going from Step 1 to Step 2. I don't understand how they are doing this. How does the $-4b$ magically become positive and then 5 become 6? I'm obviously missing something. What is it?
\begin{align*}
    3a−5&=−4b+1\\ 
    4b &= 6 -3a\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we are really invoking are some nice (intuitive properties) of the numbers. For starters note that $b$ does not become positive. Instead we add $4b$ on both sides of the equation:

$$3a-5=-4b+1\implies 3a-5+4b=-4b+1+4b$$.

Hence we $3a-5+4b=1$. Now add $5-3a$ on both sides to get $4b=6-3a$.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. 4b does not become positive, but because we add it to both sides it disappears from one side and reappears on the other side because it doesn't have an off setting value.

Answer (score 2):

$$3a-5 = -4b+1 \to 3a -5 +4b = -4b + 4b +1$$
adding $4b$ to both sides
$$3a-5+4b=1 \to 3a -5 +5 +4b =1+5$$ 
adding 5 to both sides
$$3a +4b =6 \to 3a +4b -3a = 6 - 3a$$ 
taking 3a from both sides
 $$4b = 6-3a$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Remember that at each step, what we do to one side of the equation we must do to the other.

Try to find a series of steps that would lead you to that answer.

> $3a−5=−4b+1 \implies 3a=-4b+6 \implies 4b+3a = 6 \implies 4b = 6 -3a$

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle is: If $x\color{red}{+c}=y$, then $x=y\color{blue}{-c}$.

So, the missing steps are:
$$\begin{align}
3a\color{red}{−5} =−4b+1 & \implies 3a = - 4b + 1 \color{blue}{+ 5}
\\ \color{red}{3a}  = -4b + 6 & \implies  0 = {-4b} + 6 \color{blue}{- 3a}
\\  0 = \color{red}{-4b} + 6 - 3a & \implies \color{blue}{+4b } = 6 - 3a
\end{align}$$